# I have 'expression changed after it has been checked error 'if I use *ngif, but it not appears if i use [hidden]

Tags: angular, hidden, angular-ng-if

I have a big doubt, case 1 produces an error, but if I substitute case 2 does not fail.

Case 1:

```
 <div class="col-8" *ngIf="customstreetType">
    <app-input-text
      [valueIn]="_address?.custom_street_type"
      (valueOut)="_address.custom_street_type = $event; change()"
    ></app-input-text>
  </div>
```

Case 2:

```
  <div class="col-8" [hidden]="!customstreetType">
    <app-input-text
      [valueIn]="_address?.custom_street_type"
      (valueOut)="_address.custom_street_type = $event; change()"
    ></app-input-text>
  </div>
```

Error:

```
DemandsActionAddressComponent.html:21 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:7594)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:7582)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:7684)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:10545)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:10534)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:11137)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11065)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (DemandsActionAddressComponent.html:21)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11054)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:10433)
```

I don't understand why it is happening. *ngIf is more fast than [hidden] or something like this?

Comment: your code can work with *ngIf also. you can add changedetectorref after you are changing the value of "customstreetType" example   `constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {customstreetType =false;cd.detectChanges()}`

Comment: Oh, this is very interesting information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They work differently. `*ngIf` can put or remove a component inside DOM (and all that goes with it, like firing relevant lifecycle hooks, `ngOnInit`, `ngOnChanges`, `ngOnDestroy` etc. for the element and every element inside it).

Meanwhile, `[hidden]` adds a 'hidden' attribute to the element, but doesn't affect component(s) life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

ngIF:

yes! ngIF might be slow while adding removing elements to the DOM because of intializations

No DOM element is added if ngIf evaluates to false.

Hidden :

DOM element will be added to HTML

As the element is already added to DOM showing and hiding are very fast

Comment: Ok, but why *ngIf produce a 'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError' error but [hidden] not. I don't understand that... Maybe [hidden] finish faster than *ngIf and the error doesn't happen.

Comment: you can get more info on this topic in this link

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

Comment: Ty mate, I understand now.